# Was any part of her story falsified?

Tags: the-oa

The second most confusing part about the new Netflix show [The OA](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4635282/) is when Alfonso (French)

> finds the books under OA's bed and becomes immediately convinced that she made up the entirety of the story.

Did she make up the other prisoners, or any of her story?

Comment: I think the only answer you're likely to get is "We don't know".  It's a new show, and that information hasn't been given yet.

Answer (score 6):

She survived a fall that is impossible to survive, was miraculously cured from her blindness and can tame attack-dogs.

> Then they do the dance and, as if guided by an invisible stream, nobody gets hurt except for The OA.
>   Then she dies, her favorite means of transportation, which will bring her to Homer.

I think the confusion about whether her story is real is actually just the confusion of the listeners. The story we heard is the story as the listeners interpreted it, which is why Alfonso saw himself as Homer - he identified himself with Homer.

I think it would be a stretch for her story to not be real at this point. Unless, as in American Psycho, everything is neither true nor false but purely symbolic.

Edit: Or maybe miracles happen in the show, but the ones she is talking about just happen to be made up. Which would be quite the odd stretch.

Comment: She also Youtube'd Homer very early in the season, so we have reason to believe he wasn't made up.

Answer (score 5):

I just watched the last episode and at first I had the same question. So I'm replying hoping that it might be useful for people that might look this up later.

There is indeed some strong evidence that the whole story was true:

- The fact that she was indeed missing for 7 years The youtube video of
  her playing the violin at the metro station
- The fact that she was cured from blindness
- The fact that she survived from the fall The
  influence her touch had to other creatures (i.e. the dog, the
  teacher, Steve...)
- The fact that her latest dream indeed came true
- The fact that she was injured just at the moment that the sequence of
  movements was ending
- The youtube video showing that Homer was a real person and that he indeed had a near-death experience.

The books the French found were in an amazon box, probably meaning they had been ordered together. This could be an order she did after coming back, trying to investigate more into what had happened to her. It would be more suspicious if those where child books among others in her library, showing that -being a schizophrenic- she might just mixed all those in her mind.

In my opinion the series left the ending "open", or at least without a very clear answer because the whole series was about belief. She and the prisoners needed to keep believing in order to make it, the team of 5 she collected needed to believe her without specific proofs, etc. So it is like the ending puts us into their shoes and let's us see if we do believe or not.

Answer (score 2):

In season 2 of The OA, we find out that

> the books were purchased by Prairie's father **after** she came back, to help her work through her trauma.

On top of that, we specifically see

> Prairie, Hap, and the rest of the prisoners travel to an alternate dimension.

We also see

> B.B.A. "feel" where Prairie is between dimensions, and we find out that Steve was able to travel to the "Brit" dimension to find her.

So with all of that in mind, it appears that her story was

> true.

For more spoilers, there are summaries of each episode on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_OA).